# Chrome extension manifest permissions v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Alright I'm making my first chrome extension and I've ran into a bit of a problem:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status == 'complete') changeTheme(tab);
});


function changeTheme(tab) {
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            css: "h1 { color: #212121; }"
        })
}
```

The extension devtool console logs this:
`Error: Cannot access contents of url "long ass url". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.`

How would I "Request" permission?

Comment: What's the site you are trying to inject on?

Comment: https://google.com/search

Comment: Does it work in other sites?

Comment: Nah, it weirdly gave a `Cannot access a chrome:// URL for the first line` when I go to youtube

Comment: Yeah I know, I just figured out, ignore the chrome:// error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"host_permissions"` is for matching `urls` not for permissions.

Change this:

```
"host_permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ]
```

Into this:

```
"host_permissions": [
    "https://example.org/foo/bar.html"
  ]
```

Or any other urls you want the extension to be available on (expect `chrome://`)

If you want the extension to be available on all sites use:

```
"host_permissions": [
   "<all_urls>"
  ]
```